# Text not transiting up while hovering but it does change the color

Tags: html, css

Hi hello im building a website just to practice and learn. Currently stuck on this part where the text is not transiting up, but it does change colors.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #007994;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

header {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header__links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="header__links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The following code should make the texts transition up. i tried watching videos, friends and even chatGPT, but chatgpt was just making it worse.

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

a:not(.header__logo a):hover{
    color: #007994;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand your ‘following code’. What is header__logo?

Comment: its was just the logo on the header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your links `display: block` here is a working demo.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* Notice this line */
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  color: #007994;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

header {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header__links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="header__links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```